# Datalist selection with php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I was trying to make a description table for my website and I finished the front end `javascript html/css` but I was confused on how to make the backend `mysql/php` work. 
I never used `datalist` before and someone suggested I'd use it. I've been well-aquainted with posting forms but never divs. How do you think I could grab this information if it had a datalist inside.

This is my javascript code.

```
<script>

     var onEditClick = function() {
      this.parentNode.classList.add('inEditMode');

      var content = this.parentNode.querySelector('p');
      content.setAttribute('contentEditable', true);
      content.focus();
    };

    var onSaveClick = function() {
      var parent = this.parentNode;

      var content = parent.querySelector('p');
      content.setAttribute('contentEditable', false);

      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      var params = "description="+ content.textContent;

      xhr.open("POST", parent.dataset.post, true);

      xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

      xhr.send(params);

      xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xhr.readyState === 4) {
          if (xhr.status === 200) {
            alert('Saved');
          } else {
            alert('Not saved');
          }
            }

        parent.classList.remove('inEditMode');
      };
    };

    var onCancelClick = function() {
      var parent = this.parentNode;

      parent.classList.remove('inEditMode');
      var content = parent.querySelector('p');
      content.setAttribute('contentEditable', false);
        content.blur();  
    };

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', 
    function() {
      var buttonEdit = document.createElement('button');
      var buttonSave = document.createElement('button');
      var buttonCancel = document.createElement('button');
      buttonEdit.textContent = 'Edit';
      buttonEdit.classList.add('edit');
      buttonSave.textContent = 'Save';
      buttonSave.classList.add('save');
      buttonCancel.textContent = 'Cancel';
      buttonCancel.classList.add('cancel');

      var editable = document.querySelectorAll('.editable p');
      Array.prototype.forEach.call(editable, function(single) {
        var edit = buttonEdit.cloneNode(true);
        var save = buttonSave.cloneNode(true);
        var cancel = buttonCancel.cloneNode(true);

        edit.addEventListener('click', onEditClick, false);
        save.addEventListener('click', onSaveClick, false);
        cancel.addEventListener('click', onCancelClick, false);

        single.parentNode.appendChild(edit);
        single.parentNode.appendChild(save);
        single.parentNode.appendChild(cancel);
      });
    }, false);

    </script>
```

And my html is `<div class='editable' data-id='123' data-post='/endpoint/save'>`
the endpoint save is a placeholder, but could I transfer this into a form, or how would I select this with php? to insert description value into a database?

Answer (score 0):

Datalists work like a SELECT list in that they both take the option tags to populate the list. Although you're using an input type="text", it will act like a select element and can be accessed with Javascript/jQuery for the values.

```html
<input type="text" id="theContact" class="theContact" name="theContact" list="contactlist" size="35" placeholder="none" />
<datalist id="contactlist">
  <?php
    // Populate the options here, in a logic loop grabbing the data...
    echo '<option value="' . $value . '">' . $value . '</option>';
  ?>
</datalist>
```

You can grab the value of the input element, or get the "selected" attribute you desire. Hope this helps! Please rate, thanks.